# ApiPlatform - Duplicated id field in order filter

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have i bundle that provides entities that i must use for my REST project.
Due to the bundle i must also configure the api-platform in YAML files.
I need to order a collection by its `id`.

The problem is that  got an error because the SQL is resulting with a duplicated field in `ORDER BY` clause.

```sql
ORDER BY a0_.AUCUT ASC, a0_.AUCUT ASC
```

`AUCUT` is the original name mapped to `codiceCliente` field of the entity and it's the `id` of the entity itself

This is my case

**config/api_platform/cliente.yaml**

```yaml
resources:
  Acme\Entity\Cliente\Cliente:
    shortName: 'Clienti'
    description: 'Clienti di Acme'
    collectionOperations:
      get:
        path: /clienti
        filters: ['cliente.order_filter', 'cliente.search_filter']
        openapi_context:
          summary: Recupera la lista dei clienti Acme
    itemOperations:
      get:
        path: /clienti/{id}
        requirements:
          id: '\d{1,6}'
        openapi_context:
          summary: Recupera un cliente in base al codice Acme
          parameters:
            - in: path
              name: id
              schema:
                type: integer
              required: true
              description: Codice cliente
    attributes: # optional
      input: App\Dto\Cliente\ClienteDtoInput
      output: App\Dto\Cliente\ClienteDtoOutput
      pagination_items_per_page: 25
```

**config\services.yaml**

```yaml
app.cliente_resource.order_filter:
  parent: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.order_filter'
  arguments:
    $properties:
      codiceCliente: ~
      ragioneSociale: ~
  tags: [ { name: 'api_platform.filter', id: 'cliente.order_filter' } ]
  autowire: false # required
  autoconfigure: false # required
```

Is there a way to avoid the duplication?